# Does the IsolationLevel with Entity Framework Core lock the entire database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my Web API project, I need to handle the concurrency for a certain operation, to make sure that a certain table don't get created more than a defined range.

Example: (insert into table B if table A.Count is less than Range 5)

So I was searching in how to do this and I found the `IsolationLevel` documentation and how to do it.

My question is, when used, the whole database stops working until that operation gets finished or only the tables involved?

```
var aa = await Context.HostEvents.Where(a => a.EventToken == client.EventToken).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

aa.HostGuests.Add(new HostGuests
                      {
                           ClientToken = id,
                           Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                           Status = 1
                      });
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Entity framework "*holds*" nothing. this is all done at the database level. and no it doesn't "*hold*" the entire database

Comment: Well, you get it what I was trying to say.  Thanks!

Comment: i for one have re-read this question 3 time and i'm not getting it - could you try re-wording?

Comment: @JohnB I did. Try to read now!

Comment: please explain what this means : `table don't get created more than a defined range` - you are creating tables?

Comment: There's a product in a store with only 6 of them available, (that's the range of how many products still available), and I need to make sure that the buyers only can buy those 6 items left. I can't check in Runtime if there's still items left because someone could buying that same item at the same time, so imagine if there's only ONE item left and these two buyers trying to buy, it wold exceed the range which is 6 and now 7 people would have bought and not only 6. So I need to LOCK this operation to make SURE to "stack" the calls one by one. Get it ?

Comment: As mentioned before - it's **not** EF Core that locks anything - it's the underlying database - and the behavior will depend on which concrete database you're using. For **SQL Server**, row-level locks are used, so only the **actually affected** rows are locked - unless your transaction uses more than 5000 locks at any given then, in which case SQL Server will do a "lock escalation" to the **table level** - but it will **NEVER** lock the **entire** database ......